# Restricting local communications with pfsense firewall

Tags: firewall, lan, pfsense

I am new here and got some questions :

1- I have a local network with two groups of users : Restricted and non-Restricted, for Restricted users I use an alias with proper rules list and static dhcp mapping, my question is : is there a way to prevent those two groups from connecting to each other with some exceptions (I noticed they can connect with each other when the firewall was rebooting).

2- Can I prevent all users from connecting to internet if they don't have their IP from pfsense DHCP server ?

3- Can I use a virtual extra subnet for my lan ??

Thats it for now, thank you very much !

Comment: You need to provide more details about the topology of your network. The information provided now is ambiguous and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

answering 2: you can set all machine default gateways to the pfSense ip addy and use that as the next hop address, this will prevent any from accessing internet until pfsense is up and running

1 & 3: you can, if you set up a Vlan each for Restricted and for Non Restricted then they wont be able to communicate (unless set in an ACL or forwarded or something you have explicitly done)

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer, about point 2 : you did not get me, what I meant a local user can change his network setting from dhcp to static IP, other than what I would give him, for example I would give a restricted IP, for example 192.168.1.5 for his MAC address when dhcp request is made from his NIC, but the user would avoid the restriction by setting his IP manually to 192.168.1.10, and this actually will work, so how we stop this?